# Is there a way to protect iCalender files?

Tags: calendar, icalendar

I'm in the need to make a agenda public via a .ics file hosted on our company's website, but it needs some kind of protection to not make it accessible to other people, is there a way to put a password or something on it?

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using calDAV instead of an ICS file. That way, you can restrict access with usernames and passwords. Take a look at baikal, e.g., which is open source and very easy to implement.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, i've looked trough the documentations of different CalDAV servers. But i didn't managed to find out, but is it possible to import a .ics into the CalDAV server and bind it to a users agenda? So i can update their agenda by just uploading a new .ics?